# Making multilayer accordions with pure JS and using nextElementSibling

Tags: javascript, accordion, addeventlistener, queryselector

New to Javascript. I recently posted a question about creating multiple multilayer accordions. I got some great feedback, but someone mentioned that if my HTML was set up correctly, I could achieve the same goal by using `nextElementSibling` and thus have much cleaner JS.

I figured out how to do this using only queryselect. See the below example:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="mainAccordion">
    <h2>dropdown one</h2>
    <h3>dropdown two</h3>
    <p>content content content content</p>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.mainAccordion {
    background-color:lightblue;
    width:200px;
    margin:auto;
    padding:3%;
}
.mainAccordion :nth-child(1){
    background-color: blue;
    padding:3%;
    cursor:pointer;
    color:white;
}

.mainAccordion :nth-child(2){
    background-color:yellow;
    cursor:pointer;
    max-height:0;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.mainAccordion :nth-child(3){
    font-weight:bold;
    max-height:0;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

**And the JS:**

```
var mainAccordion = document.querySelector(".mainAccordion").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    if (e.target.nextElementSibling.style.maxHeight) {
        e.target.nextElementSibling.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
        e.target.nextElementSibling.style.maxHeight = e.target.nextElementSibling.scrollHeight + "px";
    }
});
```

This works as intended. However, when I introduce multiple multilayer accordions and switch to "querySelectorAll", it stops working. Also depending on the browser, I sometimes get an error message saying my "addEventListener" is not a function.

See below:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="mainAccordion">
    <h2>dropdown one</h2>
    <h3>dropdown two</h3>
    <p>content content content content</p>
</div>

<div class="mainAccordion">
    <h2>dropdown one</h2>
    <h3>dropdown two</h3>
    <p>content content content content</p>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
body {
    display:flex;
    width: 900px;
    margin:auto;
}
.mainAccordion {
    background-color:lightblue;
    width:200px;
    margin:auto;
    padding:3%;
}
.mainAccordion :nth-child(1){
    background-color: blue;
    padding:3%;
    cursor:pointer;
    color:white;
}

.mainAccordion :nth-child(2){
    background-color:yellow;
    cursor:pointer;
    max-height:0;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.mainAccordion :nth-child(3){
    font-weight:bold;
    max-height:0;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

**and JS:**

```
var mainAccordion = document.querySelectorAll(".mainAccordion").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    if (e.target.nextElementSibling.style.maxHeight) {
        e.target.nextElementSibling.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
        e.target.nextElementSibling.style.maxHeight = e.target.nextElementSibling.scrollHeight + "px";
    }
});
```

I've tried changing "querySelectorAll(".mainAccordion") to getElementsByClassName("mainAccordion") but also doesn't work.

Is forEach somehow involved?

Note: I know you can also achieve the same goal by toggling a class that has the "max-height:0;overflow:hidden". However, this was how I was initially taught to do accordions.

This is for my own practice.

I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
let accordionElements = document.querySelectorAll(".mainAccordion");

    accordionElements.forEach(element => {
        element.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
            if (e.target.nextElementSibling.style.maxHeight) {
                e.target.nextElementSibling.style.maxHeight = null;
            } else {
                e.target.nextElementSibling.style.maxHeight = e.target.nextElementSibling.scrollHeight + "px";
            }
        })
    });
```

It's because with querySelector() an HTML Element is return. With querySelectorAll() it's a NodeList. In your sample code you try to attach an event to a node list which is not possible.

You need to loop inside and then attaching the event to each HTML Element inside.

Comment: Thank you, Jeremie! I am still wrapping my head around ES6 syntax and its use of arrow of functions. The course I took must have been old and used ES5. Just to help me understand, if line 2 were written in ES5 it would be "accordionElements.forEach(element){...}"?

Comment: My pleasure ! In ES5 you should write accordionElements.forEach(function(element) {}. Here the main benefits was to not have to write function. But Arrow function have other good benefits: binding this to the surrounding context, implicit return and the arrow "=>". This is a good article about arrow function: https://www.sitepoint.com/es6-arrow-functions-new-fat-concise-syntax-javascript/

Answer (score 0):

i think that the problem is that the `querySelector()` returns the first Element within the document that matches the specified selector. then the event listener will be applied to the first element found.

the `querySelectorAll()` returns a list. you could use it with `forEach` like this

```
  var mainAccordion = document.querySelectorAll(".mainAccordion");
  console.log(mainAccordion);
  mainAccordion.forEach(accordion => {
    accordion.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
      if (e.target.nextElementSibling.style.maxHeight) {
        e.target.nextElementSibling.style.maxHeight = null;
      } else {
        e.target.nextElementSibling.style.maxHeight =
          e.target.nextElementSibling.scrollHeight + "px";
      }
    });
  });
```